# Mesh seems weird after applying solidify modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am modelling a car.i applied solidify modifier on the mirrors of the car and it is mesh is looking messed up.Is this normal?Should i worry about it during final render?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply the modifiers in the order you created them, otherwise the results will be unpredictable

Comment: I haven't applied any modifiers yet and the mesh looks as in ss above.

Answer (score 0):

mmm... make sure you don have overlapping faces, try to select one face (vertex or edge), then select connected (l), move them along the z axis and see if what happens. If so, try to join them (m). You can also try recalculate normals or try to remember if you duplicated that object with some solidify modifier applied. You can also try to model that part from scratch. Definitely that error will show in the final render